# Type providers samples with Visual Studio Beta

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2012, type-providers, f#-3.0

Good news, Type Providers now use Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.**FSharpExpr** instead of **Linq** Expressions

Bad news, many samples do not work anymore, the ones using ProvidedTypes-0.1.fs .....

Do you know where to get a hold on updated samples /  ProvidedTypes-0.x.fs ?

update:

Unless I am mistaken, the providers located in YourFSharp3SampleBeta\SampleProviders in the Sample F#3.0 have not been updated.

Comment: Definitely a question valid only at some point in time. I voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [latest checkin](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/11798) to the [F# 3.0 Sample Pack](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/) includes [ProvidedTypes-0.2.fs](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/11798#235400).

Comment: Indeed. Thank you. I am very confused by the codeplex website.

Answer (score 2):

The download section has been updated. The download section has two files, one is for preview version which will be supported for another 3 months and the latest one is for beta release.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361034(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: weird. it says CURRENT
FSharp 3.0 Sample Package
DATE
Sat Sep 17 2011 at 9:00 AM. checking..